# Eigenvalues of Kronecker Product

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, kronecker-product

Maybe it's simple but I can't see the solution of this problem (Russell Merris, *Multilinear Algebra*, CRC Press, 1997, chapter 6, p.202, exercise 4):

> Let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_p$ be the eigenvalues of $A\in\mathbb C_{p,p}$ (multiplicities included), and $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_q$ be the eigenvalues of $B\in\mathbb C_{q,q}$ respectively. Find the eigenvalues of
>
> a. $A \otimes B - B \otimes A$.
>
> b. $A \otimes B + B \otimes A$.

From chapter 5, I know the eigenvalues of $A\otimes B$ and $A\otimes I_q + I_p \otimes B$:

1. The eigenvalues of $A \otimes B$ are $\lambda_i \cdot \omega_j$, $1 \leq i \leq p$,  $1 \leq j \leq q$
2. The eigenvalues of $A\otimes I_q + I_p \otimes B$ are $\lambda_i + \omega_j$, $1 \leq i \leq p$,  $1 \leq j \leq q$

These facts may give us a decomposition of $A\otimes B \pm B \otimes A$.

This may be very simple but I need a hint.

I also made some Matlab calculations with integer matrices, and I get non-integer/non-real eigenvalues... maybe square roots are involved...

Thanks!

Comment: What are the dimensions of the matrices $A$ and $B$? Are they the same? What about the dimension of $I$?

Comment: Edited the dimensions

Comment: I understand what you are saying. You are right! This is not possible find the desired eigenvalues. I have deleted the answer.

Comment: @AlexSilva Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: Is it just the difference of the eigenvalues?

Comment: @Bombyxmori can you be more explicit? I can't see why it's the difference if I get nonreal eigenvalues with A and B with integer eigenvalues...

Comment: I think the author has simply left out some additional conditions. From his wording, he seems to imply that the eigenvalues of $A\otimes B\pm B\otimes A$ depend solely on the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$, but this is not true. E.g. when $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$, the spectra of $A\otimes B+B \otimes A$ and $A\otimes B-B \otimes A$ are respectively $\{-1,1,0,0\}$ and $\{-i,i,0,0\}$. However, if we replace $B$ by the zero matrix (that has the same spectrum as the original $B$), all eigenvalues of $A\otimes B\pm B \otimes A$ are zero.

Comment: By the way, $A\otimes B\pm B \otimes A$ is not decomposable in general.

Comment: In page 110 of the book https://books.google.pt/books?id=-dia2irg1WQC&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=eigenvalues+of+kronecker+product+A%E2%8A%97B-B%E2%8A%97A&source=bl&ots=cF3fe-euZX&sig=wOcMCa2PTPpV24BGHsY4JzTFqGU&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ei=yVqxVOxBg-dSqMiA8Ag&ved=0CB4Q6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=eigenvalues%20of%20kronecker%20product%20A%E2%8A%97B-B%E2%8A%97A&f=false we can find the same exercise and the conditions are the same... and before the exercise list one can find some properties of the Kronecker Product that maybe can help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have Merris' book, but something seems to be forgotten in the question - in the present form it cannot be answered.

Consider, for instance, diagonal matrices $A$ and $B$ explicitly given by
$$A=\operatorname{diag}\left\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\right\},\qquad
B=\operatorname{diag}\left\{\omega_1,\omega_2\right\},$$
so that
\begin{align}
&A\otimes B+B\otimes A=\\
=\,&\operatorname{diag}\left\{2\lambda_1\omega_1,\lambda_2\omega_1+\lambda_1\omega_2,
(\lambda_2+\lambda_3)\omega_1,(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\omega_2,\lambda_3\omega_1+\lambda_2\omega_2,2\lambda_3\omega_2\right\}.
\end{align}
The spectrum of the last matrix is not invariant e.g. with respect to the exchange $\omega_1\leftrightarrow\omega_2$.

Furthermore, even setting $p=q$ as in the book referenced in the comment does not save the situation: again consider diagonal $2\times 2$ matrices $A,B$ and notice that the spectrum of $A\otimes B+ B\otimes A$, given by $\{2\lambda_1\omega_1,\lambda_1\omega_2+\lambda_2\omega_1,\lambda_1\omega_2+\lambda_2\omega_1,2\lambda_2\omega_2\}$ is not invariant w.r.t. the exchange of eigenvalues of one of them.