# Showing $2\left\|(H\otimes H) \left(I\otimes H+H\otimes I\right)^{-1}\right\|=\|H\|$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $H$ is a positive definite $n\times n$ matrix. What is the easiest way of showing the following for operator norm $\|\cdot\|$?

$$2\left\|(H\otimes H) \left(I\otimes H+H\otimes I\right)^{-1}\right\|=\|H\|$$

Context: I'm looking to simplify proofs of Jain/Kakade [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03774). This expression is Eq.2 of paper with $b$ taken to $\infty$

Comment: SVD? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Is $\otimes$ the Hadamard product?

Comment: @Kroki $\odot$ is Hadamard, $\otimes$ is Kronecker

Comment: @Kroki it is [Kronecker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) product

Comment: Is this link helpful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095323/eigenvalues-of-kronecker-product. Just focus on the information about eigen values

Comment: Let $h_1\ge h_2\ge\cdots\ge h_n$ be the eigenvalues of $H$. Then $\max_{i,j}\frac{2h_ih_j}{h_i+h_j}=\max_{i,j}\frac{2}{h_i^{-1}+h_j^{-1}}\le\frac{2}{2h_1^{-1}}=h_1=\|H\|$.

Comment: @user1551 thanks, that's concise. That inequality should be equality I think

Comment: Yes, it’s an equality.

Comment: Strange that this question was closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $H$ is positively definite, $H$ can be written as $U^T\Lambda U$, where $U^TU = I$ and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with positive eigenvalues on the diagonal. $H\otimes H = (U^T\Lambda U) \otimes (U^T\Lambda U) = (U^T\otimes U^T)(\Lambda\otimes \Lambda )(U\otimes U)$, which is eigenvalue decomposition of $H\otimes H$. Similarly, since we have $U^TU = I$, we have
$$
H\otimes I + I \otimes H = (U^T\otimes U^T)(\Lambda \otimes I + I \otimes \Lambda)(U\otimes U) 
$$
Take matrix inverse:
$$
(H\otimes I + I \otimes H)^{-1} = (U^T\otimes U^T)(\Lambda^{-1} \otimes I + I \otimes \Lambda^{-1})(U\otimes U) \\
(H\otimes H)(H\otimes I + I \otimes H)^{-1} = (U^T\otimes U^T)(\Lambda \otimes \Lambda)(\Lambda^{-1} \otimes I + I \otimes \Lambda^{-1})(U\otimes U) 
$$

Now, note that the operator norm is the largest eigenvalue of the matrix. Therefore, we can see that the identity holds.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the last bit is done using user1551 expression